# Not able to file a bug with attachment on Bugzilla 5.0.2 Perl 5.2 on xampp windows 7

Tags: perl, xampp, bugzilla

I completed setting up of Bugzilla v5.0.2 on xampp in windows system with the help of this link: https://thiscouldbebetter.wordpress.com/2015/10/23/installing-bugzilla-on-windows-with-xampp/.

I can file a bug without attachment, but with attachment I am not able to file bugs. I am getting this error message:

> Error in tempfile() using template \xampp\tmp\XXXXXXXXXX: Parent directory (\xampp\tmp) does not exist at C:/Perl/lib/CGI.pm line 3382.

[[image: Screen shot of the error message]]

I rewrote path rules in httpd.conf file.

location of bugzilla in my system : C:/bugzilla/

location of xampp : D:\development\xampp

Please help me on this issue, I am not able to fix from past 2 days.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXnxh.jpg)

Comment: Have you considered using one of the [Bugzilla support channels](https://www.bugzilla.org/support/)?

Comment: Yeah. But could not get proper solution. But just now i fixed this by my own. I created dummy xampp\tmp folders inside C: dirve. i.e C:/xampp/tmp.      Now i can upload bugs with attachment. Anyway thanks @MattJacob

Comment: Added markup and screenshot